# How to test KNN model on a different dataset

Tags: r, validation, testing, knn

How can I test a KNN model (KNN.predMale8) on a different dataset? What formula should I use?

different data:
KNN.validMale0               (variables)

KNN.validMale.valid.labels   (labels)

```
 KNN.predMale8 <- knn(KNNdataMale.train, KNNdataMale.test, KNN.dataMale.train.labels, k = 8)
```

I feel like it would be wrong if I do exactly the same steps again for the different dataset, instead of importing the previous created model.

Comment: What about `predict(KNN.predMale8, newdata = your new data set)`?

Comment: You can use the `caret` package with  `knn_model <- train(...(your data, variables)...method ="knn")` and  make a prediction with the `predict()` function

Comment: thank you. It seems like there is no way to not use the caret package for that